# Character to Date conversion

Tags: sas

```
Data test;
x="20161";
run;
```

I have a date "20161" (that is 'jan2016') as character ,now I want to show it as "jan2016",howcan I do this?

Comment: You can use formats. `PROC FORMAT` allows you to create your own format to change how your data looks: 
http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/001-30.pdf

Comment: How would two-digit months appear, if you care about those? "201610"?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you start with a string variable, and you want the result to be a string variable?  That seems potentially limiting, since dates are more easily manipulated as numbers.

Taking your request literally, I would parse the first 4 characters of the provided string, and make them the year.  Then I would treat all other characters like the month.  We'll create a true date (numeric var) out of this with the MDY() function, by assuming that day=1.

That gives us an intermediate numeric variable, that we'll pass to the PUT() function so that we can convert the number into a string in your desired MONYY7. format.  The final piece is that you want the output string lowercase, so we'll wrap the final result in a LOWCASE() function.

```
Data test;
x="20161"; *the input;
y = mdy(substr(x,5),1,substr(x,1,4)); *a temporary intermediate variable that's a date/numeric var;
z = lowcase(put(y, MONYY7.)); *convert back to string in the desired format, and lowercase it;
drop y; *no longer needed;
run;
```